# Error when adding parameters to ADODB command in a .NET assembly 2

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, com, .net-assembly, adodb

This question is related to,
[Error when adding parameters to ADODB command in a .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818552/error-when-adding-parameters-to-adodb-command-in-a-net-assembly)

I came across this post and was able to resolve my issue from its answer.
However, my issue was little different.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc;
cmd.CommandText = "GetUserPreferencesBasedOnScreen";
cmd.let_ActiveConnection(conn);
conn.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;
object dummy = Type.Missing;
Parameters paramets = cmd.Parameters;
int paramCount = paramets.Count;
for (int iParams = paramCount - 1; iParams >= 0; iParams--)
{
    paramets.Delete(iParams);
}
Parameter pMtr = cmd.CreateParameter("Screen_Name", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50);
paramets.Append(pMtr);
```

The last line throws the following error

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
 'ADODB.InternalParameter'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be 
cast     to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to
interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for
the IID of the interface.
```

When I am using .Net framework 3.5 this code was not giving error.
Now, as soon as I changed the framework to 4.0 I started getting this error.

Please let me know if there are any alternatives to use 2.8 otherwise I will have to test everthing again to make sure nothing else broke with adoption of 2.7.

Comment: MSDN says, in 2.8 the following was enhanced.
Recordset.ActiveCommand returns an error when invoked from an HTML/ASP page.
This prevents the Command object from being misused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you're using `ADODB` but the easiest solution is to use the .NET standard stuff in System.Data, like [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This is consistent across .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0. (And ADODB is *old*!)

Comment: The one that you answered is an altenative. But not an answer. However, I am removing downvote, as it is not incorrect to use alternative. But I have a requirement to use old one here, until I am able to change it to .net completely.